# ARM, VFP, floating-point, lazy context switching

Tags: gcc, floating-point, arm, osdev

I am writing an operating system for an ARM processor (Cortex-A9).

I am trying to implement lazy context switching of the floating-point registers. The idea behind this is that the floating-point extension is initially disabled for a thread and so there is no need to save floating-point context on a task-switch.

When a thread attempts to use a floating-point instruction, it triggers an exception. The operating system then enables floating-point extension and knows that floating-point context must be saved for this thread in the next context switches. Then the floating-point instruction is re-executed.

My problem is that the compiler generates floating-point instructions even when no floating-point operations are used in c code.
This is an example of a disassembly of a function that uses no floating point in c:

```
10002f5c <rmtcpy_from>:
10002f5c:   e1a0c00d    mov ip, sp
10002f60:   e92ddff0    push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, sl, fp, ip, lr, pc}
10002f64:   e24cb004    sub fp, ip, #4
10002f68:   ed2d8b02    vpush   {d8}
...
10002f80:   ee082a10    vmov    s16, r2
...
10002fe0:   ee180a10    vmov    r0, s16
...
1000308c:   ecbc8b02    vldmia  ip!, {d8}
...
```

When I have many of such functions, lazy context switching makes no sense.

Does anybody know how to tell the compiler that floating-point instructions should only be generated when there is a floating point operation in the c code ?

I use gcc 9.2.0. The floating point options are: `-mhard-float -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfp`

Here is a example c function (not useable, only a demo):

```
void func(char *a1, char *a2, char *a3);
int bar_1[1], foo_1, foo_2;

void fpu_test() {
    int oldest_idx = -1;
    while (1) {
        int *oldest = (int *)0;
        int idx = oldest_idx;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (++idx >= 3)
                idx = 0;
            int *lec = &bar_1[idx];
            if (*lec) {
                if (*lec - *oldest < 0) {
                    oldest = lec;
                    oldest_idx = idx;
                }
            }
        }
        if (oldest) {
            foo_1++;
            if (foo_2)
                func("1", "2", "3");
        }
    }
}
```

gcc command line:

```
$HOME/devel/opt/cross-musl/bin/arm-linux-musleabihf-gcc  -O2 -march=armv7-a -mtune=cortex-a9 -mhard-float -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfp -Wa,-ahlms=fpu_test.lst -mapcs-frame -c fpu_test.c -o fpu_test.o
```

Assembler listing:

```
...
  35 0000 0DC0A0E1      mov ip, sp
  36 0004 003000E3      movw    r3, #:lower16:foo_2
  37 0008 F0DF2DE9      push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, r10, fp, ip, lr, pc}
  38 000c 006000E3      movw    r6, #:lower16:foo_1
  39 0010 003040E3      movt    r3, #:upper16:foo_2
  40 0014 04B04CE2      sub fp, ip, #4
  41 0018 006040E3      movt    r6, #:upper16:foo_1
  42 001c 004000E3      movw    r4, #:lower16:bar_1
  43 0020 028B2DED      vpush.64    {d8}                <=== this is the problem
...
```

Comment: all of those options are telling the compiler to build for floating point, do you have an example/minimal C function that demonstrates the problem and a full gcc command line (or enough to demonstrate the problem)?

Comment: I updated my post with a example c function with the gcc command line and part of the assembler listing

Comment: -mapcs-frame
Generate a stack frame that is compliant with the ARM Procedure Call Standard for all functions, even if this is not strictly necessary for correct execution of the code. Specifying -fomit-frame-pointer with this option causes the stack frames not to be generated for leaf functions. The default is -mno-apcs-frame. This option is deprecated.

Comment: if I remove that then this push goes away (as does the stack frame which is a waste of a register)

Comment: removing -mapcs-frame works for simple functions. In my project the number of vpush instructions was reduced, but they are still there.

Comment: Is there not a PSR bit to indicate that floating point registers have been written to since the last time it was reset (e.g. at context switch)?  This is how lazy FP context switching often works on other architectures (the saving part, at least - you'll still need an exception for if read).

Comment: I have not found such a bit in the PSR. The FPEXC.EX bit is interresting, but I do not fully understand how it works. ARM-ARM says: 0=A context switch can be performed by saving and restoring the values of these registers, 1=There is additional state that must be handled by any context switch system.
In another document I found that when FPEXC.EX is 1, then the FPINST and FPINST2 registers have to be saved when changing context (in addition to the context registers). So it seems this is not the bit I am looking for. Any hints ?

Answer (score 1):

[GCC has a command-line switch for this, `-mgeneral-regs-only`.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.1.0/gcc/ARM-Options.html#ARM-Options). When using the command-line switch, you may need to separate code that deliberately uses floating-point registers or operations into separate source files so that it can be compiled without that switch.

[As of GCC 9.3 (perhaps 9?), for ARM targets, this is available as a function attribute:](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Function-Attributes.html#ARM-Function-Attributes)

```
void MyFunction(char *MyParameter) __attribute__ ((general-regs-only));
```

Putting the attribute after the declaration is an older syntax and required a non-definition declaration. Testing suggests GCC now accepts an attribute before the declarator and may be used with a definition:

```
void __attribute__ ((general-regs-only)) MyFunction(char *MyParameter)
{...}
```

You may also be able to negate the attribute with `__attribute__ ((nogeneral-regs-only))`, although I do not see this documented.

This can also be controlled with a [pragma](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.1.0/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html#Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas).

There are also `+nofp` options within the `-march` and `-mcpu` switches, but I think `-mgeneral-regs-only` is what you want.

Comment: Yes, -mgeneral-regs-only compiles c functions without floating-point to a code with no Floating-Point registers. But then I have to separate c code into files with and without floating-point. Thats not wat I want.

Comment: It got an error with '__attribute__ ((general-regs-only))'. Maybe this is not available in gcc 9.2.0. Nevertheless this attribute forces me to touch the sourcecode, what I want to avoid.

Comment: @ErwinP: If you cannot use the command-line switch and do not want to modify the source code, I do not have much hope there is a solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just note related to function attribute:
`__attribute__ ((general-regs-only))` seems not working on gcc 9.3.1.

Try the 'target' attribute. For example:

```
void __attribute__((target("general-regs-only"))) MyFunction(char *MyParameter)
{...}
```

Negation of "general-regs-only" seems not working on gcc 9.3.1.