# Is there a compilation option to stop gcc using floating point instructions in integer code?

Tags: gcc, arm64, bare-metal

My integer-only, bare-metal C project just ground to a halt when I got an unexpected exception about a floating point instruction.

Looking at the gcc generated code, the culprit is an `fmov d0, x0`, used to temporarily store a value in a floating point register, rather than on the stack.

I don't want it to do that!

I could mark a function or two with the `noinline` attribute, but that's no guarantee that the problem won't occur again elsewhere.

Comment: there was just a question about this the other day...

Comment: You mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62029562/arm-vfp-floating-point-lazy-context-switching/62036050 ? "ARM, VFP, floating-point, lazy context switching" What search do you suggest I should have used to find that as an answer to my question? Other than -mgeneral-regs-only, which I didn't know about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This option does the trick:

```
-mgeneral-regs-only
```

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.1.0/gcc/AArch64-Options.html

> Generate code which uses only the general-purpose registers. This will prevent the compiler from using floating-point and Advanced SIMD registers but will not impose any restrictions on the assembler.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inform compiler that your target does not have floating-point hardware. The exact flag depends on your target (for ARM it's `-msoft-float`).

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think Aarch64/arm64 has that option. Anyway, I found -mgeneral-regs-only

Comment: @SimonWillcocks As I mentioned this depends on the target e.g. MIPS even has `-mno-float` (and you didn't mention AArch64 in your question).

Comment: You're right, I just tagged it. Sorry, I'm new at this site. Thanks, anyway.